# Goodix tp not work with I2C

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, touch-screen

I used nanopi 2 fire from friendlyarm.I want to work with GT911 goodix touch panel. it has 6 pin: 1 for reset(i just connected to one of gpio), 2 for vdd3.3 volt,3 for GND, 4 for irq (i connect it to gpioc11) and SDA and SCL (connect to pin 3 & 5 as I2C-0). I download Linux kernel 4.4.y with this source code to active goodix touch screen:

```
git clone https://github.com/friendlyarm/linux.git -b nanopi2-v4.4.y --depth 1
```

I active goodix as the module in the kernel, and follow the [page](http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/Core4418#Compile_Linux_kernel_4.4.y) to compile kernel , at last copy the files to SD.(run make command,copy zimage and dtb file to boot sd). when I run this code:

```
root@NanoPi2-Fire:/# find -iname goodix*
./sys/bus/i2c/drivers/Goodix-TS
./sys/firmware/devicetree/base/soc/i2c@c00a6000/goodix_ts@5d
./sys/firmware/devicetree/base/soc/i2c@c00a6000/goodix_ts@5d/goodix,irq-gpio
```

and for detect i2c i have:

```
root@NanoPi2-Fire:~# ls -l /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan  1  1970 /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-0 -> ../../../devices/platform/c0000000.soc/c00a4000.i2c/i2c-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan  1  1970 /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-1 -> ../../../devices/platform/c0000000.soc/c00a5000.i2c/i2c-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan  1  1970 /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-2 -> ../../../devices/platform/c0000000.soc/c00a6000.i2c/i2c-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan  1  1970 /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-3 -> ../../../devices/platform/c0000000.soc/c0000000.soc:i2c@3/i2c-3
```

and :

```
root@NanoPi2-Fire:/# i2cdetect -y 0
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --                         
root@NanoPi2-Fire:/# i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --                         
root@NanoPi2-Fire:/# i2cdetect -y 2
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --                         
root@NanoPi2-Fire:/# i2cdetect -y 3
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --      
modprobe goodix_ts
modprobe: FATAL: Module goodix_ts not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.49-s5p4418
```

How to use gt911 on linux?

Comment: If you see Godix entries under /sys, the driver should already be loaded (verify with `lsmod`, assuming you compiled the driver as a module. If you didn't, compile it as a module, much easier to test this way.). Look into the output of `dmesg` after boot (or after you attach the device) to see if there are any godix-related messages (don't grep, context is important). If everything works, the touchpad will likely show up as kernel input devices in `/dev/input` (use `evtest` on them), but the `dmesg` output will probably give you details on that.

Comment: thanks for the reply. at first, can I ask you a question? Is there any config for 'int' and 'reset' gpio pin in the source of a kernel or in the device?where am I set irq and reset pin for GT911? and also I will check that you said. really thanks for help

Comment: The proper drive should control the reset pin, and it should also route the IRQ pin properly so it generates an interrupt. First place to look is the source code of the driver and/or at the module parameters. (I haven't done this; I haven't even google dthe source code of the driver, but since you compiled it, you should have it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add something like this to the device tree (dts) you use for your kernel:

```
&i2c1 { /* Use the correct name of the bus you're device is on */

 - other dts code here -

    gt911: touchscreen@14 {
            compatible = "goodix,gt911";
            reg = <0x14>;
            interrupt-parent = <&gpioc>; /* Use the correct gpio controller here */
            interrupts = <11 IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_FALLING>;
            irq-gpios = <&gpioc 11 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
            reset-gpios = <&gpioc ? GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>; /* Use the correct gpio controller and pin */
    };

 - other dts code here -
```

};

See the device tree bindings here:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/input/touchscreen/goodix.txt

When both the IRQ and RESET pins can be controlled by the driver, it will automatically configure the chip for the address you supplied in the device tree.
(It does this by resetting the gt911 with the correct INT level set and switches back the line to an input)
In the above case its 0x14 the other usable address is 0x5d.

NOTE: When you have an unidirectional INT line: It is not a hard requirement to use the reset line via the driver if you have only an unidirectional signal (such as using a buffer between it). Just make sure the GT911 is reset correctly and supply the address that you have configured during reset.

Comment: Sorry if its not quite connected to the question, but you'll help me a lot with a little similar mine. I also have goodix touchpanel connected to rpi zero w, all works for me, but its hard to find 6 pin slim connector for it - is there a way not to use rst at all, so I can connect with usb socket? I mean as I understood it is used only at startup, I can pull it off after handshake. And I'm using default 0x14 address all the time, so I dont need it actually.

Comment: Just leave out the "reset-gpios" definition in the DTS and (indeed) use the default I2c slave address. That should work. By the way: The interrupt is required so you need at least 5 pins to do the job (VCC, GND, SCL, SDA, INT).